# TFS-2015 limiting user list

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

After upgrading to TFS 2015 we are seeing all users in the collection being displayed as options for the Assigned To fields of a Work Item.

In 2013 we had set an ALLOWEDVALUES rule set to [project]\Contributors. It would restrict the list in the drop down to only the values in that group.

Now the drop down shows everyone and only complains if you try to select a user from the complete list that is NOT in the contributors groups.

How do we get the old behavior back?

Answer (score 7):

In many organization, the work item type is shared across many teams. The old dropdown was long and was cluttered with people you would never assign a work item to. We heard a lot of requests to make assigning to people a much better experience.

We have changed the work item control to a MRU control so people you care about most show up immediately. And there is a "search more" option to find people which are not in the MRU yet.

We are aware that it is not possible anymore to restrict the list with the rules you define on the work item. It was an explicit design decision, and the rule is still enforced on save as you indicate.

Ewald Hofman - TFS Program Manager

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! This has been haunting my TFS admin skills for a while now, trying to figure out why it *seemed* that new users added to our AD domain weren't "showing up" in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps:

1. Creat a collection level group.  Team Explorer-->Team Project Collection Settings-->Group Membership-->New-->Group name: MyTeam--> Double-click [your collection]\MyTem-->select Windows User or Group-->Add-->add users
2. Create a "Issue" work item type. Tool-->Process Editor-->Work Item Types-->Open WIT from server-->Copy an existing work item type and change the name as "issue".
3. In Field tab, double-click Assigned To-->Rules-->New-->ALLOWEDVALUES-->in ALLOWEDVALUES window, click New-->in List Item Edit window, enter [Project]\MyTeam-->OK, then save this work item type.
   [image]

For test:
4. Create a new "issue" item, in Assigned To drop down list, you can only see the users you add in MyTeam.

Comment: this is actually exactly what I did. We are trying to create a custom WIT and there are several new fields with each tied to a different custom group. There appears to be new behavior in the Web app only. If I use the Visual Studio 2015 interface it works as expected showing only the users in the list. The Web app controls now show 'history' but of what I am not sure.

Comment: Working well in VS means your settings are correct.Problems may arise in your IE Exploer. Sign out your account of your web access,clean IE cache,close IE.Reopen it, then try again.

Comment: The unwanted behavior persists after clearing cache and restarting. Using TFS 2015 and IE 11.