# TFS 2015 Assigned to not showing list of members

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I setup TFS 2013 scrum template late last year and was using it without issue. When adding a new PBI or BUG on the Web Portal and tabbing into the Assigned To field I was able to start typing or drop down the list to see all the members of the Team Project.

After upgrading to TFS 2015 the list is gone and type ahead does not work. If I type the first few characters of a member and click search I am able to find a member, but this is cumbersome when going through and trying to quickly add a PBI or BUG.  FYI this also happens when adding a new Bug as well as tasks on both a PBI and Bug.

[image]

Comment: This is just an attempt at smart loading. It's because the person that you are trying to assign to doesn't have any previous assignments in that team so it may be cumbersome the first time but then next time you can type and tab as you normally would

Comment: See my answer to another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33183593/422565