# Invalid work items impact

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

During the time some work items are becoming invalid. The AssignedTo field (which is mandatory) has a value of a deleted account (people are leaving the organization).

What's the impact of these invalid work items on TFS performance/health?
Most of them are in Closed state so it's small chance that someone will open them again.

Should I maintain all work items in valid state?

Answer (score 0):

**For  AssignedTo field** ,you can remove the deleted and unused account by some settings.You need to add `ALLOWEDVALUES` rules with the project group which you want to be displayed in AssignedTo field. Please refer my answer in [TFS-2015 limiting user list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108621/tfs-2015-limiting-user-list/33122403#33122403) for more info.

**For invail work items**, it doesn't has any serious influence. There are general three treatments.

1. Just ignore it
2. Change the `AssignedTo`  to others
3. If this work item will not be used in the future, you can [delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908.aspx) it.

In the near future, easy way of deleting and recycleing a work item is coming on.

> Visual Studio Team (Product Team, Microsoft) responded  ·  Aug 29,
>   2015
>   We’ve started work on this one. We’re planning to add a real delete
>   into the UI… complete with a recycle bin. High level plan is to
>   deliver this around November of 2015.
>
> Source: [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3317366-easy-way-delete-a-task-or-work-item-in-team-founda#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)