# TFS Work Item AssignedTo dropdown missing items

Tags: tfs, tracking, workitem

I added a TFS group [Projects]\Business Analysts.  Some of the people assigned to this group do not show up in the dropdown.  Anyone know why this would happen? 
Additionally, when I access the AssignedTo field from the context menu on the backlog page the names are completely different than those on the Product Backlog AssignedTo List.

Here is work item definition for the group:

```
  <FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
      <LISTITEM value="[Project]\Business Analysts" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <HELPTEXT>Organizer of product feature</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the people that are not showing up part of the project in any way? Did you put the full group inside one of the OOB groups (contributors, Admins, etc.) or in a team in this project.  If the missing individual don't have access to the project they won't show up in the dropdowns this rule doesn't add them to the project just filter user in that group in the assigned to field.

Answer (score 0):

> **Some of the people assigned to this group do not show up in the
>   dropdown.**

The drop down is actually a cached list of users you have assigned tasks to in the past.

So, **you just need enter their first name or email address to search him and assign to him. Next time, you will see him in the drop down list**.

Details steps:

1. When assigning a user to a task, enter their first name and click the search button. The user should be brought back by the search. Assign the user to the task.
2. Next time you go to assign a user to a task, if you click on the drop down list should now display the user as it is now cached.

For details please take a look at *Ewald Hofman's* response in this question:  [TFS-2015 limiting user list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108621/tfs-2015-limiting-user-list/33183593#33183593)

If you still not able to see those users after manually search their name/e-mail, then you may have to check the corresponding permission. Make sure all of them have sufficient permissions.

Hope this helps.